# Firing up a stand-alone Selenium RC server on (Ubuntu) Linux from Perl

Tags: linux, perl, selenium, ubuntu

I recently moved from Windows to Ubuntu Linux so I have a porting job. One of my applications is a web testing one interacting with a Selenium RC server, programmed in Perl 5.22. The application fires a Selenium server at the beginning, exchanges messages with it and shuts it down at the end.

On Windows, the Firing code is:

```
my $selenium_call_string = qq(start cmd /c java -jar  selenium-server-standalone-2.53.0.jar -firefoxProfileTemplate \"$firefox_profile_dir\");
system ($selenium_call_string);
```

This produced a separate terminal window in which the Selenium log is rolling, whereas the Perl script is writing into the original Terminal window from which it was invoked.

How do I achieve the same result on (Ubuntu) Linux?

Comment: By the way, those backslashes are redundant. `qq(\"...\")` is the same as `qq("...")`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without trying I think you need to run a `system qq{xterm -e "java -jar..."}` command in your `system` command [from askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/484993/run-command-on-anothernew-terminal-window)

Comment: Works as advertised   :-) Thanks! Meir